# Odd FSM behavior with counter signals

Tags: vhdl

I am attempting to use a state machine to route AXI4-Stream signals and encapsulate them in network layer headers.

I am using discrete states for each header to be appended, the payload, and then the Ethernet FCS data at the end. Within these states, the fields themselves and the index of them that I'm writing is through an integer I'm calling tx_wordcnt. However, through transitions I'm not getting the values I want.

For example, once I have a message to transmit, I want to first go to writing the Ethernet header. Here are the relevant parts to my state machine as it transitions over to the write_eth_header state.

```
process(tx_pstate, tx_fcs_data_fsm, tx_axis_udp_tready_fsm, tx_axis_mhif_tdata,
         tx_axis_mhif_tvalid, tx_axis_mhif_tlast, tx_mhif_src, tx_mhif_dest,
         tx_mhif_len, tx_mhif_chksum, tx_mhif_ip_dest, tx_mhif_mac_dest)
begin

  case(tx_pstate) is
  
    when idle =>
      tx_wordcnt <= 26;
      tx_axis_udp_tlast_fsm   <= '0';
      tx_axis_mhif_tready     <= '0';
      if(tx_axis_mhif_tvalid = '1') then
        tx_axis_udp_tvalid_fsm <= '1';
        tx_axis_udp_tdata_fsm  <= x"AA";
        tx_msg_done            <= '0';
        tx_crc_en_fsm          <= '1';
        tx_crc_clr_fsm         <= '0';
        tx_nstate <= write_eth_header;
      else
        tx_axis_udp_tvalid_fsm <= '0';
        tx_axis_udp_tdata_fsm  <= (others => '0');
        tx_msg_done            <= '1';
        tx_crc_en_fsm          <= '0';
        tx_crc_clr_fsm         <= '1';
        tx_nstate <= idle;
      end if;
    
    when write_eth_header =>
      tx_axis_udp_tvalid_fsm  <= '1';
      tx_axis_udp_tlast_fsm   <= '0';
      tx_axis_mhif_tready     <= '0';
      tx_msg_done             <= '0';
      tx_crc_en_fsm           <= '1';
      tx_crc_clr_fsm          <= '0';
      if(tx_wordcnt > 19) then -- Preamble
        tx_axis_udp_tdata_fsm <= x"AA";
      end if;
      if(tx_wordcnt = 19) then -- Start Frame Delimiter
        tx_axis_udp_tdata_fsm <= x"AB";
      end if;
      if(tx_wordcnt > 12 and tx_wordcnt <= 18) then -- MAC Destination
        tx_axis_udp_tdata_fsm <= tx_mhif_mac_dest((tx_wordcnt-13)*8+7 downto (tx_wordcnt-13)*8);
      end if;
      if(tx_wordcnt > 6 and tx_wordcnt <= 12) then -- MAC Source
        tx_axis_udp_tdata_fsm <= tx_mhif_mac_src((tx_wordcnt-7)*8+7 downto (tx_wordcnt-7)*8);
      end if;
      if(tx_wordcnt > 2 and tx_wordcnt <= 6) then -- 802.1Q Tag (Optional)
        tx_axis_udp_tdata_fsm <= (others => '0');
      end if;
      if(tx_wordcnt > 0 and tx_wordcnt <= 2) then -- Ethernet Payload Length
        tx_axis_udp_tdata_fsm <= eth_len_int((tx_wordcnt-1)*8+7 downto (tx_wordcnt-1) * 8);
      end if;

      if(tx_axis_udp_tready_fsm='1' and tx_wordcnt > 0) then
        tx_wordcnt <= tx_wordcnt - 1;
        tx_nstate  <= write_eth_header;
      elsif(tx_axis_udp_tready_fsm='1' and tx_wordcnt = 0) then
        tx_wordcnt            <= 20;
        tx_axis_udp_tdata_fsm <= x"45";
        tx_nstate             <= write_ip_header;
      else
        tx_nstate <= write_eth_header;
      end if;
```

However, tx_wordcnt skips state 25 completely (it should actually start at 25 but I'm using 26 to account for this skip). The three signals here from top to bottom are tx_nstate, tx_pstate, and tx_wordcnt:

[image: Transition to write_eth_header]

I am seeing another issue with tx_wordcnt when the message payload is written and the FSM transitions to writing the Ethernet FCS data at the end. Here are the two states it transitions between:

```
  when write_msg_payload =>
    tx_axis_udp_tlast_fsm   <= '0';
    tx_axis_mhif_tready     <= tx_axis_udp_tready_fsm;
    tx_msg_done     <= '0';
    tx_crc_clr_fsm  <= '0';
    
    if(tx_axis_mhif_tvalid = '1' and tx_axis_mhif_tlast = '1' and tx_axis_udp_tready_fsm = '1') then
      tx_axis_udp_tvalid_fsm  <= '1';
      tx_axis_udp_tdata_fsm   <= tx_fcs_data_fsm(31 downto 24);
      tx_crc_en_fsm   <= '0';
      tx_wordcnt <= 4;
      tx_nstate  <= write_eth_fcs;
    else
      tx_axis_udp_tvalid_fsm  <= tx_axis_mhif_tvalid;
      tx_axis_udp_tdata_fsm   <= tx_axis_mhif_tdata;
      tx_crc_en_fsm   <= '1';
      tx_nstate <= write_msg_payload;
    end if;
    
  when write_eth_fcs =>
    tx_axis_mhif_tready    <= '0';
    tx_crc_en_fsm          <= '0';
    
    if(tx_axis_udp_tready_fsm='1' and tx_wordcnt > 0) then
      tx_axis_udp_tvalid_fsm <= '1';
      tx_axis_udp_tdata_fsm  <= tx_fcs_data_fsm((tx_wordcnt-1)*8+7 downto (tx_wordcnt-1)*8);
      tx_msg_done            <= '0';
      tx_crc_clr_fsm         <= '0';
      tx_wordcnt <= tx_wordcnt - 1;
      if(tx_wordcnt = 1) then
        tx_axis_udp_tlast_fsm <= '1';
      else
        tx_axis_udp_tlast_fsm <= '0';
      end if;
      tx_nstate  <= write_eth_fcs;
    elsif(tx_wordcnt = 0) then
      tx_axis_udp_tvalid_fsm <= '0';
      tx_axis_udp_tdata_fsm  <= (others => '0');
      tx_msg_done            <= '1';
      tx_crc_clr_fsm         <= '1';
      tx_nstate              <= idle;
    end if;
```

And again, the waveform of tx_nstate, tx_pstate, and tx_wordcnt:

[image]

tx_wordcnt initializes to 4 as it should, but then immediately gets stuck at 1 on the next clock cycle. I'm not sure why this is happening. Additionally, during this time, tx_axis_udp_tready is '1' and of course tx_wordcnt > 0, so I don't know why the conditional requiring this in the write_eth_header state doesn't seem to evaluate and decrement tx_wordcnt to 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the process provided, `tx_wordcnt` is missing from the sensitivity list. This causes unexpected behavior in simulation.

Comment: This was it. In fact, in order to avoid infinite loops I needed signals ns_wordcnt and ps_wordcnt just like pstate and nstate, made ps_wordcnt <= ns_wordcount on clock rising edge, and assign ns_wordcnt within the process (whenever it should be decremented, I used ns_wordcnt <= ps_wordcnt - 1;). ps_wordcnt is in the sensitivity list.